# Objective-C add functionality to every method of an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

i want to build  a small plugin-system for objects in objective-c.

Now i am stuck at the point where i want to dynamically (at runtime) add a line of code to every function available in an object.

I have played around with the runtime library but came to no solution, yet.

What i have tried so far is this:

```
        id (^impyBlock)(id, id, ... ) = ^(id self_, id arguments, ...)
        {
            // My custom code for every function here
            id (*func)(__strong id,SEL,...) = (id (*)(__strong id, SEL, ...))imp;
            return func(obj, s, arguments);

        };

        id (*impyFunct)(id, SEL,...) = imp_implementationWithBlock(impyBlock);
        method_setImplementation(mList[i], impyFunct);
```

My problem is, when there is more than one argument i got no chance to pass them to "func()". AFAIK this is not possible in C.

Another solution i have thought about is doing some magic with method swizzling.

In steps:

1. Create a "swizzle Method" which just calls my custom code and calls the original method afterwards (by a naming schema)
2. Change the IMP of every function with the one of the "swizzle Method"
3. Create a new method with the "old" implementation and change to name to a schema like "___name"

In this solution i am stuck at point 3. I haven't managed to dynamically create a complete new method.

Does anybody can help me with my problems above or has another solution for a "catch all method functionality".

The best would be something like forwardInvocation which also catches already defined functions.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is some fairly intense black magic. Are you sure you need to do this? I love fiddling around with stuff like this myself, and support it, but there may be a better way to accomplish your _true_ goal.

Comment: Do you have any other ideas for a plugin system where i can "hook" in every function of an object. (The hooking part works quite well, but calling the original implementation is the key of the problem)

Comment: Having done something similar, maybe I can save you some time: You will eventually hit a brick wall when you get to variadic methods (i.e. methods like `stringWithFormat:`). If that's a deal breaker for you, I advise you to give up now.

Comment: This may be relevant to your interests as well: https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc (specifically see `EXTAspect`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lemme break this into two parts since I just can't get the connection between your two questions.

I. Create a new method with the "old" implementation and change to name to a schema like "___name"

That's fairly easy, although I don't understand how that would be able to solve your problem. You still can't pass down variadic function arguments to such a method (and you're right, that can't be done in C).

```
IMP swapImpForSelector(Class cls, SEL sel, IMP newImp)
{
    Method m = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, sel);
    IMP oldImp = method_setImplementation(m, newImp);

    NSString *newSel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"__prefixed_%@", NSStringFromSelector(sel)];
    const char *type = method_getTypeEncoding(m);
    class_addMethod(cls, NSSelectorFromString(newSel), oldImp, type);

    return oldImp;
}
```

II. If you want to pass variadic arguments between functions, you may need to fall back to heavy assembly hackage. Fortunately, some smart people have already done that for you.

Either use the [NSInvocation class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html), or if it isn't sufficient, then [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/) is even lower-level.

Comment: Oh, using "class_addMethod" was easy, thank you for that! My plan is indeed building an NSInvocation dynamically. I'll give it a try. Thx!

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks! Works perfectly. Was trying to add functionality to a static library class's viewWillAppear that I did not have access to. This allowed me to still fire their viewWillAppear and add more functionality afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this for arbitrary objects will be quite hard. Take a look at [AspectCocoa](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/AspectCocoa) for something along these lines, but you'll see it doesn't work so great and isn't recommended for use in a production environment.

But for a plugin system, you'd be better off just defining something like a PluggableObject class that is designed with extension in mind. Forget about running arbitrary blocks in the middle of arbitrary methods — instead, define specific "sockets" where things can plug in and an interface that those things can follow to get the functionality you want to support. It'll be a lot more stable and easier to add and fix things.

Comment: That's the point, i want to avoid extension under all circumstances. For example, i also want to make an UIVIewcontroller "pluginable", so inheritance doesn't fit here. Maybe "Categories" could help me? But i haven't found how to extend existing methods with this pattern. Another idea is using NSProxy, but with this solution i loose all the compiler checks...